# Gerbers to PCB conversion - Altium

Tags: altium, pcb-layers

I am new to Altium. I am trying convert gerber files in to PCB. I am getting following error while trying to extract net-list.
It is asking me to compress or redefine layers. I dont know how to do that.

**Error I am getting while extracting Netlist.**

[image]

**Layer stack**

[image]

Comment: Can you use a Gerber Viewer to see which are duplicates and disable them?

Comment: Generally Altium is very good at answering these type of questions. They are afterall experts at they're own products. Have you considered asking Altium or the Altium forum ?

Comment: I think that you need to take a look at your source Gerber files, and determine which of the duplicates you wish to use.  I suspect that you really should not need to compress any of the duplicate layers.  Instead, just decide which layers to import, and which ones to ignore.  The duplicate layers are likely design revisions for various reasons (different paste mask expansions, and the like).

Comment: I disabled some duplicate layers and was able to export netlist and then pcb

Comment: send me the grebers files , because i work on same project and i have no company email